# Unable to remove Bitnami info page banner for AWS Cloud EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami

As per [these instructions](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/bninfo/) provided by Bitnami, in order to remove the info page banner. I must log into my EC2 instance via SSH. However, when I created the website I did not make a key pair. So as far as I am aware I am unable to connect to the instance by SSH. Is there a way I can change this? I do not just want to hide the banner with a CSS hack.

Comment: Have you looked at userdata?

Comment: You should be able to create a key pair using the instructions in this link below. https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/starting-bitnami-aws/credentials_ssh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way to remove the banner is to log in to into your server console using SSH and execute some commands (if not anyone could eliminate it without having permissions), AFAIK you can't apply a keypair to a running instance. You can only use the new keypair to launch a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below mentioned steps to remove Bitnami info page banner for AWS Cloud EC2 or any other hosting

login with wp-admin ->
Dashboard -> Appearance -> Customize -> Additional CSS ->

```
#bitnami-banner {
    display:none;
}
```

If above code will not work simply add !important

```
#bitnami-banner {
    display:none !important;
}
```